# Remove whitespace to left and right of div at smaller screen resolutions using CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using a div.wide tag in my stylesheet to display a fullscreen graphic at the top of a page.

```
div.wide {
   height:500px;
   background-image: url(http://www.vidalingua.com/images/pont-des-invalides.jpg);
   background-position: 50%;
   background-size: cover;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

When I reduce the screen to smaller widths, as would be seen on a phone, whitespace margins begin to appear. 
http://vidalingua.com/blog/top-travel-blogs-for-france.php

How can I solve remove the whitespace to left and right of image at smaller screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    }
}
```

change this to

```
    @media (max-width: 767px){
    body {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom, .navbar-static-top {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you try reset `padding` in `body` it will create horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I can see a lot of negative margin to elements in the website. This is the reason scroll had came to body.Please correct the negative margins else website codes will look messy and will cause compactibility issues
}

Comment: I can see the bootrap is edited.Its a good practice not to edit bootstrap.css.I edited my answer slightly please try it and let me know what issue you are facing still.

Comment: can you understand that **I'm not the OP?** I didn't ask the question at all. and you are wrong bootstrap wasn't edited at least in that part

Comment: oo yaa.. since you are eagerly commenting i thought its you.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have this rule in `bootstrap.css`'s media query `max-width:767px`

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}
```

so you need to add negative `margin` inside that query, something like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.wide {
     margin: 0 -20px
  }
}
```

If you try reset `padding` in `body` it will create horizontal scrollbar.